# Apache 2 Location Blocks

Tags: apache, location, apache2, apache2.4

Im trying to do some basic auth on Apache2 but allow a specific file through with no auth. Not sure what im getting wrong as i believe I have the correct syntax for ech block.

base location block: works perfectly fine

```
<Location />
            MellonEndpointPath /mellon
            AuthType "Mellon"
            #MellonEnable "auth"
            Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Catch locationmatch for any path that ends with / : Works perfectly fine

```
<LocationMatch "^/*">
            MellonEndpointPath /mellon
            AuthType "Mellon"
            #MellonEnable "auth"
            Require valid-user  
</LocationMatch>
```

and then finally the allow specific file location block

```
<Location /*/example.pac>
            Require all granted
</Location>
```

Is the locationMatch overriding the specific location block, or is my syntax incorrect?

Thanks

Comment: `Catch locationmatch for any path that ends with / ` <-- this is incorrect, you are matching any path that *begins with* `/`. It will therefore match everything, so the final block won't be applied

Comment: Thanks @arco444, I have removed that block, but still seeing the same issue, authorization being applied when it shouldn't be.

Comment: Actually @arco444 you were right, I had to do an additional location block.